# Passing CoreData Container from UITabBar to another VC

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uikit

i want to pass the container from my Tabbar to my VC, I tried to do it something like this, but does not work at all. How do I fix it?

My VC

```
class FavVC: UIViewController {
    var container: NSPersistentContainer!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard container != nil else { fatalError("This view needs a persistent container.") }
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        ])
    }
}
```

My Tabbar

```
class TabBar:UITabBarController {
    
    var container: NSPersistentContainer!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var TabBarContent: UITabBar!
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let favVC = segue.destination as? FavVC {
            favVC.container = container
        }
       }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard container != nil else { fatalError("This view needs a persistent container.") }
        print("it works!")
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to use segue here, because `UITabBarController` do navigation automatically. Try to implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate`, add this extension for your TabBar class:

```
extension TabBar: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if let favVC = viewController as? FavVC {
            favVC.container = container
        }
        
        return true
    }
}
```

Then modify TabBar `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.delegate = self
    
    guard container != nil else { fatalError("This view needs a persistent container.") }
    print("it works!")
}
```

Now you have container before FavVC viewDidLoad call.

Answer (score 0):

If any of you have the same struggle as I do.
You can simply add

```
if let tabBarVC = self.tabBarController as? TabBar {
            self.container = tabBarVC.container
        }
```

on your UIViewController